# async await does not perform as expected on multiple sequential invocations | angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, chaining

For each index I trigger loadFeed() function and expect each query to Real Time Database to be executed sequentially. When I pass 5 indexes in a row [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] one after another ~ loadFeed(0, 10); loadFeed(1,10); loadFeed(2,10), etc., the output is looking like this:

```
 index rendered: 4 with limitToLast with === 0 
 index rendered: 2 with limitToLast with === 0  
 index rendered: 0 with limitToLast  
 index rendered: 3 with limitToFirst with !== 0
 index rendered: 1 with limitToFirst
```

**Expectation is this:**

```
index rendered: 0 with limitToLast
index rendered: 1 with limitToFirst
index rendered: 2 with limitToLast with === 0
index rendered: 3 with limitToFirst with !== 0 
index rendered: 4 with limitToLast with === 0
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem or faced the same issue before?

**Source Code:**

```
async loadFeed(index, iter) { 

    var that = this;

    // WAITING ROOM FOR THE OBJECTS 
    await this.sortedLoad(index, iter, that); 

  }


  async sortedLoad(index, iter, that) {

    var left =  index % iter;

    if (index === 0 ) {
      return await that.rdb.database.ref('f/u/' + that.gl.currentUser + '/').orderByChild('date').limitToLast(1).once('value', snap => {
        that.cum.push(snap.val());
        console.log('index rendered: ' + index + ' with limitToLast');
        return snap;
      });
    } else if (index === 1) {
      return await that.rdb.database.ref('f/u/' + that.gl.currentUser + '/').orderByChild('date').limitToFirst(1).once('value', snap => {
        that.cum.push(snap.val());
        console.log('index rendered: ' + index + ' with limitToFirst');
        return snap;
      });
    } else {

      if (left === iter-1) {
        return await that.rdb.database.ref('f/u/' + that.gl.currentUser + '/').orderByChild('date').limitToFirst(1).once('value', snap => {
          that.cum.push(snap.val());
          console.log('index rendered: ' + index + ' with limitToFirst');
          return snap;
        });
      } else {

        if ( index % 2 === 0 ) { // EVEN
          return await that.rdb.database.ref('f/u/' + that.gl.currentUser + '/').orderByChild('date').limitToLast(1).once('value', snap => {
            that.cum.push(snap.val());
            console.log('index rendered: ' + index + ' with limitToLast with === 0');
            return snap;
          });
        } else if ( index % 2 !== 0 ) { // ODD
          return await that.rdb.database.ref('f/u/' + that.gl.currentUser + '/').orderByChild('date').limitToFirst(1).once('value', snap => {
            that.cum.push(snap.val());
            console.log('index rendered: ' + index + ' with limitToFirst with !== 0');
            return snap;
          });
        } 

      }

    }
  }
// -----
```

Function that calls loadFeed()

```
private chunks = 5;
public cum = []; // render url results
private outputListener  = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
private obs: Observable<any>;

      this.obs = this.outputListener.asObservable().scan( (acc, val) => {
        //if (String(val[0]) === 'refresh') {
          return acc.concat(val);
      });

      // EACH NEW ITEM HITS HERE
      this.obs.subscribe(data => {

        this.items = data.length;
        const iter = 10;
        const index = this.items - 1;  // true array index
        if (index > -1) {
          this.loadFeed(index, iter); // KICK OFF EACH LOAD HERE
        }
      });

      for (var i = 0; i < this.chunks; i++) {
        this.outputListener.next([i]);
      }
```

*Update*

So I changed each new item rendering function with await, but still get the same sporadic index output

```
// EACH NEW ITEM HITS HERE
this.obs.subscribe(async data => { // Added async

  this.items = data.length;
  const iter = 10;
  const index = this.items - 1;  // true array index
  if (index > -1) {
     await this.loadFeed(index, iter); // KICK OFF EACH LOAD HERE // Added await
   }
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are making calls to `loadFeed` function?

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: you should `await` calls to your `this.loadFeed(index, iter);`. the way you've put it when ever you have `scan` return custom iteration value, you fire-and-forget `loadFeed`. thus, you get random results back.

Comment: @deezg pointed out the issue, you can verify it by logging the index before calling the loadFeed function, it'd prove the point.

Comment: Thanks @deezg! I will try that and let know how this goes

Comment: @deezg I have updated the code with applying await to this.loadFeed(index, iter) and still get the same sporadic output. I would expect this.loadFeed to get executed sequentially and return console.log one after another is deemed finished/completed, which is not the case here. I am still wondering what the approach should be

Comment: sorry, i haven't realized the way you actually iterate original BehaviorSubject and create iterations. what you need is something different than what i initially proposed. you need `concatMap` before `scan`. you put `loadFeed` call into `concatMap` and what it will do is it will wait until `loadFeed` finishes before it emits next iteration. look at this example: https://dev.to/_builtbyjay/creating-observables-from-an-array-of-sequentially-completing-promises-273k

Comment: @deezg that worked. thanks!

Comment: glad it helped!